# Is there an OpenAL programming guide from Apple?

Tags: iphone, openal

I can't find any. Maybe there is one, anyways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenAL is included in [Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html).

iPhone specific information can be found in [Technical Note TN2199](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2199.html).

From there, you will eventually find [OpenAL Programmers Guide](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf), from OpenAL itself.